# How to send..........hreadStar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a tapPage with Viem model and i am making a toast from VM but i am getting an exception

```
TabMenuMyArticlesava.Lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I don't want to `DisplayAlert,` how else can i display an alert to user from MVVM? I found this 
 But i am not really sure how if that is not connected only to Xamarin.Android

```
 new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                    {

                        RunOnUiThread(() => { Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "xxxxxx", ToastLength.Short).Show(); });
                    })).Start();
```

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs with an IoC container and injecting IUserDialogues for use anywhere in your view models.

Answer (score 1):

use [MainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread)

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "xxxxxx", ToastLength.Short).Show();
});
```